# The measure of $[0,{1}/{q}]^n$ is $1/q^n$ for any measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have some measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying

1. Empty set has measure of zero
2. Measure is non-negative
3. Monotonicity
4. Countable sub-additivity
5. Countable additivity
6. Normalization (unit cube has measure 1)
7. Translation invariance

I need to demonstrate that given these properties, a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ must satisfy
$$m\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{q}\right]^n\right) = m\left(\left(0,\frac{1}{q}\right)^n\right) = \dfrac{1}{q^n}$$
for any $q\in\mathbb{N}, q>1$. In the hints it is said that the proof can be done in three steps:

I. Show that $m\left(\left(0,\frac{1}{q}\right)^n\right) \leq \dfrac{1}{q^n}$

II. Show that $m\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{q}\right]^n\right) \geq \dfrac{1}{q^n}$

III. Show that $m\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{q}\right]^n/ \left(0,\frac{1}{q}\right)^n \right) \leq \varepsilon$

from which the assertion follows directly. I only managed to show (I), and I am very much stuck here. Any help with II and III would be appreciated :). Below is my proof for I

Proof: To show (I) we partition $(0,1)^n$ into translates of $(0,1/q)^n$:
\begin{align*}
    [0,1]^n &\supset (0,1)^n\\
    &= \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \dots \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \left( \dfrac{j_1-1}{q},\dfrac{j_1}{q}\right] \times \dots \times \left( \dfrac{j_{n-1}-1}{q},\dfrac{j_{n-1}}{q}\right] \times \left( \dfrac{j_n-1}{q},\dfrac{j_n}{q}\right) \\
    &\supset \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \dots \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \left( \dfrac{j_1-1}{q},\dfrac{j_1}{q}\right) \times \dots \times \left( \dfrac{j_{n-1}-1}{q},\dfrac{j_{n-1}}{q}\right) \times \left( \dfrac{j_n-1}{q},\dfrac{j_n}{q}\right)
    \end{align*}
The partitioning can be justified by the fact that we can always find an integer $a$ with $a-1 < xq \leq a \iff \frac{a-1}{q} < x \leq \frac{a}{q}$.

By normalisation axiom
\begin{align*}
    1 &= m([0,1]^n)\\
    \end{align*}
    By monotonicity
    \begin{align*}
&\geq m((0,1)^n)\\
&\geq m\left(\bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \dots \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{q} \left( \dfrac{j_1-1}{q},\dfrac{j_1}{q}\right) \times \dots \times  \left( \dfrac{j_n-1}{q},\dfrac{j_n}{q}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
By countable additivity (these sets are disjoint)
\begin{align*}
&= \sum_{j_1=1}^{q} \dots \sum_{j_1=1}^{q} m\left(\left( \dfrac{j_1-1}{q},\dfrac{j_1}{q}\right) \times \dots \times  \left( \dfrac{j_n-1}{q},\dfrac{j_n}{q}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
By translation invariance
\begin{align*}
&= \sum_{j_1=1}^{q} \dots \sum_{j_1=1}^{q} m\left(\left(0,\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^n \right)\\
&= q^n \cdot m\left(\left(0,\dfrac{1}{q}\right)^n \right)
\end{align*}
as desired.